# hover effect on social icons in header?

Tags: php, css, wordpress

I want to have a semi trasparent hover effect on my social icons but cant figure it out.
Here is my header.php:

```
<div align = "right"><a href="https://twitter.com/#!/ideviceguys"><img src="/wp-includes/images/twitter.png"/></a>
<a href="http://www.facebook.com/ideviceguys"><img src="/wp-includes/images/facebook.png"/></a>
<a href="mailto:info@ideviceguys.com"><img src="/wp-includes/images/mail.png"/></a>
```

I see alot off people saying to edit css but i cant find this in my css

here is my website http://ideviceguys.com

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a hook for your css code. 
Give your div an id or class. 
Try adding class="socialIcons to your main div.

```
<div class="socialIcons">
    <a href="https://twitter.com/#!/ideviceguys"><img src="/wp-includes/images/twitter.png"/></a>
    <a href="http://www.facebook.com/ideviceguys"><img src="/wp-includes/images/facebook.png"/></a>
    <a href="mailto:info@ideviceguys.com"><img src="/wp-includes/images/mail.png"/></a>
</div>
```

Then add this little nugget to your css.

```
.socialIcons a:hover {
opacity:0.7; filter:alpha(opacity=40); /* Damn MS and IE8 and earlier */
}
```

That should give your icons 30% transparency.
Consider what the others say around here. They are much smarter than I am.

Comment: I just tried this and didnt exactly work here is my website http://ideviceguys.com

Comment: You are getting there. You need to wrap your three links in a div and give the div the class socialIcons. The cod I gave you is for any image (img) in the div with a class "socialIcons". I'll grab your code.

Comment: Thanks sorry this is a bit confusing for me.

Comment: Hey, we all have to learn sometime. I actually just updated the answer again. You should use the CSS I just added that has the transparency on the actual links. That will still make the images transparent because they are in the link.

Comment: I am still not getting the effect.... I feel like i am probably just missing something simple

Comment: To the style.css at the bottom

Comment: I found it in your style.css file. You didn't close the styling above it. You need to add } after width: 475px; for the .connect-div. That should do it.

Comment: No problem. Good luck with the rest of the site.

Answer (score 0):

You have to define it in css. First give your menu an id or class so your css can target it in a non-generic way.

```
<div class="nav">
    <a href="https://twitter.com/#!/ideviceguys"><img src="/wp-includes/images/twitter.png"/></a>
    <a href="http://www.facebook.com/ideviceguys"><img src="/wp-includes/images/facebook.png"/></a>
    <a href="mailto:info@ideviceguys.com"><img src="/wp-includes/images/mail.png"/></a>
</div>
```

in css:

```
.nav{
    float:right;
}

.nav a{
    display:block;
    float:left;
    margin-right:10px;
}

.nav a:hover{
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 10px #ff6600;
}
```

Obviously this is just an example. I have no idea what your actual design calls for. I am merely showing you that a parent element with a class of nav can select the a tags within and assign an effect on hover. This is trivial, intro level css. A more specific response will require a more detailed question.